# div on hover with jquery go away

Tags: jquery, css, html

I am using this jquery code to show div on hover:

```
$(function() {
  $('#div1').hover(function() { 
    $('#div2').fadeIn(); 
  }, function() { 
    $('#div2').fadeOut(); 
  });
});
```

on jSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4z2zq/4/

This will use two DIV ID:

1. div1
2. div2

But when `#div2` get hovered I can't click on those links! 
This div get disappear when i try to click on those links. Any idea to keep `#div2` while hovering `#div2` itself.

Comment: A simple solution might be to make `div2` a child of `div1`. That won't work for everyone though. http://jsfiddle.net/9aEmk/

Comment: thanks for that, but any css to div1 get extended with the hovered div2 http://jsfiddle.net/9aEmk/1/

Comment: True, unless you override the css on div2.

Comment: add css for both div id : http://jsfiddle.net/9aEmk/3/

Answer (score 2):

Something like that

```
$(function() {
    $('#div1').hover(function() { 
        $('#div2').fadeIn(); 
    } );
    $('#div2').mouseleave(function() {                  
        $('#div2').fadeOut(); 
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4z2zq/8/

Answer (score 1):

You just need to nest `div2` inside of `div1`.

```
<div id="div1">hover over me
    <div id="div2">
        <ul>
            <li><a href='Google.com'>Google</a></li>
            <li><a href='Google.com'>Yahoo</a></li>
            <li><a href='Google.com'>AOl</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

The above will work, and all I did was move the `</div>` from line 1 to the end. Which makes `div2` a child of `div1`.

[Here is a working fork of your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2hLh2/)

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap `div2` within `div1`.

```
<div id="div1">hover over me
    <div id="div2">
        <ul>
            <li><a href='Google.com'>Google</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href='Google.com'>Yahoo</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href='Google.com'>AOl</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/4z2zq/6/)

Answer (score 1):

For me, the best way is to change the HTML code:

```
<div id="div1">hover over me
    <ul id="div2">
        <li><a href='Google.com'>Google</a></li>
        <li><a href='Google.com'>Yahoo</a></li>
        <li><a href='Google.com'>AOl</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put `div1` and `div2` inside a wrapper `div` and bind the `hover` event to the wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

i suggest you use CSS pseudo functions for this, and put the manipulated element inside the parent (#div1) e.g:

```
#div2{
  display:none;
}

#div1:hover #div2 {
  display: block;
}
```

you wont have fancy transitions unless you use CSS 3 transitions which will limit Cross Browser capabilities.